# Which DNS to configure for Azure APIM Internal, Public DNS or Private DNS?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway, azure-dns

Thanks for A2A,

I am configuring my Azure APIM service as internal inside VNET & I am integrating it with Azure Application Gateway. Thing is I didn't get which DNS to configure for Custome DOmain setting Public DNS or Private DNS zones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Create a public IP address for the front-end configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway#create-a-public-ip-address-for-the-front-end-configuration), you should configure Public IP and [Configure the front-end IP with it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway#step-3-2).

```
$publicip = New-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $resGroupName -name "publicIP01" -location $location -AllocationMethod Dynamic

$fipconfig01 = New-AzApplicationGatewayFrontendIPConfig -Name "frontend1" -PublicIPAddress $publicip
```

And once the gateway is created, you need to [CNAME the API Management proxy hostname to the **public DNS** name of the Application Gateway resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway#cname-the-api-management-proxy-hostname-to-the-public-dns-name-of-the-application-gateway-resource).

So you can choose public DNS based on the official document.

Comment: Thanks, Allen,

One query over your reply, " Then how App GW can proxy to APIM". Do in APIM we need to set up custom domain from Private zone  or same public domain can be integreted automatically in APIM

Comment: @adityaMehta You should use the Application Gateway's DNS name  to create a CNAME record, which points the APIM proxy host name to this DNS name. Any difficulty on doing this?

Comment: Prior to this Q&A  I had done setup using Azure Private DNS zone. But APPGW won't able to proxy/connect to APIM Backend (as per health probe).
So now will go with creating a Public DOmain from a Registrar and map A record with APPGW.

Comment: @AllenWu And once the gateway is created, you need to CNAME the API Management proxy hostname to the public DNS name of the Application Gateway resource. - Does this mean you need a CNAME record with an alias pointing some something like ffhfghfhfh.cloudapp.net (this being the api gatewaay dns record created by azure)?